# Using a pointer to an array passed as a parameter of a function

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, int

I'm a beginner in C and I'm trying to use a pointer in my function.

I'm trying to fill an array of `int` by using a pointer passed as an argument of the function, but I don't know how to do it properly.

How can I do this correctly?

**Function**

```
int validate_ip(char *ip, int *ptid) { /*function where I want to use it*/ }
```

`ip` is a char array that contains an ipv4 address.

**Main**

```
int main() {

    int ipv4[4];
    int *ptid = ipv4;

    //rest of my programm
}
```

Comment: `ipv4` should be an array of `16` ("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX").

Comment: So, the question is, how do I convert an IP address string to an `int`?

Comment: @FiddlingBits i corrected my errors. The question is how can i affect my int in my function to my array ipv4 using his pointer.

Comment: With `int *ptid = ipv4;` you are _correctly_ assigning the address of the array of integers to the pointer-to-integer variable. You can now write e.g. `int i= ptid[2];`. The rule is that when you mention the array name without indexing it, the array name is converted to the address of its first element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the ipv4 `int` array to a pointer to `int` argument, what will happen is that it will decay to a pointer to its first element, to work properly with the array inside the function you should also pass the size of the array.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int validate_ip(char *ip, int *ptid, size_t size) {

    const char delim[] = ".";
    char *token;
    size_t i = 0;

    //tokenize the ip and convert it to int
    //this is for sample purposes, octet validation should be performed
    token = strtok(ip, delim);
    while (token != NULL && i < size) {
        ptid[i++] = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    char ip[] = {"192.168.0.3"}; //sample ip
    int ipv4[4];

    if(validate_ip(ip, ipv4, 4)){
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        { 
            printf("%d ", ipv4[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This will need the validations to check if the octets in the ip char array are correct, but I believe you already done that.

One last note regarding my sample code, `strtok` will make changes in the  ip `char` array, if you want to prevent this, make a copy of it and pass it to the function instead of the original ip.

Comment: In my function, int *ip isn't my array, it's representing an other variable that I'm using.It's my entire IP adress. So to use my ipv4 array i should do validate_ip(char *ip,int *ipv4,size_t 4). And then i could give to my array, the 4 differents part of my ip adress?

Comment: @TagZK, so if I inderstand you correctly you want tp pass the char array containing your ip to the function, convert it to int and store the values in the ipv4 int array, I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: In fact i have all the function that I need to change my IP to 4 differents part and also to transltae them from char to int. I just need to understand how to fill my array with my function by using a pointer that is pointing my first case of my int array. All the strtok part,check if the text is made of digit,and if the number is between 0 and 255 i have it. I just don't understand the way to use my pointer correctly

Comment: But now, thanks to you. I have the answer that i was looking for with your edit @anastaciu

Comment: @TagZK, I should have used a valid sample ip in the code even if that wasn't the problem here, one must be realistic :)

Comment: has you an idea why I have a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error?

Comment: @TagZK, if `ip` is a string literal and you try to tokenize it, that's what happens, but it's just a guess, I'd need to see the code.

Comment: @TagZK, line 116,  `scanf("%s", &adresse);` should be `scanf("%s", adresse);`

Comment: @TagZK, in `printf("IP1:%s\n",ipv4[0]);` `ipv4[0]` is an `int` you shoud use `%d` format specifier.

Comment: All the array is fill with the first part. For example with "192.20.10.1" all are fill with 192 ...

Comment: @TagZK, it's filled but you only print the first part, try `printf("IP1:%d.%d.%d.%d\n",ipv4[0], ipv4[1],ipv4[2],ipv4[3]);`

Comment: @TagZK, take a look here https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ztcb933iuiqYqiSc

Comment: I did a for loop to print that. I just dumb i forgot to replace ipv4[0] by ipv4[i].

Comment: Thk to you alot for your help. All is fine now :D

Answer (score 0):

in C if you declare an array(ipv4[4]) it has memory for his elements and its pointer is its name(ipv4), its elements are ipv4[0],ipv4[1],ipv4[2],ipv4[3]. So if you want to pass an array to a function which modify the array(void function(int* array)) you should just use the pointer it would be function(ipv4);

But in this case you are not declaring your array as an array, you are declaring a pointer, then you dont have memory for these pointer to poin.
There are a lot of ways to get memory for these pointer, for example the function malloc or calloc. Here you are trying to assign a char* to a int* which is not the best idea because when you do ipv4[2] is equivalent to *(ipv4+2), cause ipv4 is a char* when you do ipv4+2 ipv4 grows 2*sizeof(char). So now if you do *(ptid+2) ptid increments by 2*sizeof(int) which can or can not be the same as chars.

I hope that was helpfull.

Comment: Thx for ur help! :)

Answer (score 0):

There can be warnings and problems if you try to directly equalize a pointer to an array. So my solution to this problem is making a function:

```
void equalize(int * pointer, int[] array , int size){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        pointer[i]=array[i];}
    }
}
```

Comment: And then i could use it in my function to give to my ipv4 array my int?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you have to remember on converting an ASCII string of the dotted notation of an IP address to a "int" is that it needs to be in network byte order (vs host byte order) for the various socket routines.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSB27U_6.4.0/com.ibm.zvm.v640.kiml0/asonetw.htm

There are various functions available for doing this conversion (and back to ASCII).  Look at the man pages for "inet_addr()", "inet_aton()", and the associated functions for a more detailed description.

Now, you say in your comment that ipv4 should be an array of 16, but you have it declared as an array of 4 in your code.  You need to change that.  Each of the inet routines is going to expect a null terminated string if it is one of the functions that has a dotted notation string as a parameter.

https://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_aton

It's possible that one of these functions might have what you are wanting to do in your "validate" routine also.

On the other hand, if your question is just how to convert from a generic dotted notation string to a sequence of int or byte values, that would be approached different.  If you do not know how many values are separated by the dots, you might want to consider using 'strtok' to parse the string.  For example:

```
void main (int argc, char *arg )
{
    int   i;
    char  buffer[128];
    char  *token;

    for (i = 1; i < argv[i]; i++) {
        strcpy(buffer, argv[i]);
        printf("Converting '%s'... Bytes =", argv[i]);
        for (token = strtok(buffer, "."); token != NULL; token = strtok(NULL, ".")) {
            printf(" %d", atoi(token));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The 'strtok' function is very useful in a lot of situation, but it would not work for parsing lines from a file where you have comma or tab delimited fields if some of the fields were empty.  For example, say you were parsing a comma delimited file that contained the following:

```
one,two,,four,,six
```

With strtok, you would get

```
'one'
'two'
'four'
'six'
```

whereas you probably wanted to get

```
'one'
'two'
''
'four'
''
'six'
```

To get that, you would need to write your own routine, something like this:

```
char  *ParseDelimited( char *str, char delimiter, char **resumePtr )
{
    char  *token;
    char  *p;

    if (str == NULL) {
        if (*resumePtr == NULL)
            return (NULL);

        token = *resumePtr;
        if (*token == '\0') {
            *resumePtr = NULL;
            return (token);
        }
    } else {
        token = str;

        if (*token == '\0') {
            *resumePtr = NULL;
            return (NULL);
        }
    } 

    p = token;
    while (*p != '\0') {
        if (*p == delimiter) {
            break;
        }
        p++;
    }

    /* At this point, p either points to a delimiter or a null character */
    if (*p != '\0') {
        *p = '\0';
        *resumePtr = p + 1;
    } else {
        *resumePtr = NULL;
    }
    return (token);
}
```

You would then use this routine like this:

```
char  buffer[1024];
char  *token;
char  resume;

strcpy(buffer, "one,two,,four,,six");
for (token = ParseDelimited(buffer, ',', &resume); token != NULL; token = ParseDelimited(NULL, ',', &resume)) {
    printf("'%s'\n", token);
}
```

Which would give you:

```
'one'
'two'
''
'four'
''
'six'
```